# Workaround to make css variable dependent progress-bar work on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, css-variables

I have following code that works fine in all browsers and I can pass variable values from JavaScript to CSS but when I tested this in IE, it didn't work at all.

I am trying to pass startColor and endColor to an HTML progress bar since the user can pass any color and it displays progress bar with gradient applied.

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --start-color: currentColor;
  --end-color: currentColor;
}

progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(128,128,128,0.9)), 
  linear-gradient(to left, var(--start-color), var(--end-color));
}
```

JS:

```
const customColor = 'yellow'
const startColor = 'green'
const endColor = 'black'

const element = 
   <progress 
      max="100" 
      value="85"
      style={{ color: customColor }}> 
   </progress>

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--start-color', `${startColor}`);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--end-color', `${endColor}`);

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I tried adding inline style but html progress bar doesnt respond to linear-gradient in inline style.

```
const customColor = '#FF0000'

const element = 
   <progress 
      max="100" 
      value="85"
      style={{ color: '#FF0000',
               background: `linear-gradient(to left, #00ff2e, #FF0000)`}}>
   </progress>

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Is there any other way I could achieve this since CSS Variables are not supported in IE?

Comment: CSS variables just started being supported in Edge. It will never be avaiable on IE though.

Comment: yep. I saw that online but it's required to support IE :( Is there any other way i could achieve this?

Comment: This looks to me like this could easily be solved with JavaScript, and is not necessarily a CSS question (unlike the question marked as duplicate).  Also, I'm curious why `linear-gradient` doesn't work.  I just did a quick test, and confirmed that you should be able to set a background to `linear-gradient` through JavaScript.

Comment: Agreed, @dippas - consider un-mjolniring?